# Three 8-bit Input Comparator In Verilog

Tags: verilog, comparator

I have changed my original coding to what is now listed below:

```
module comparator (
   input wire [7:0] A,
   input wire [7:0] B,
   input wire [7:0] C,
   output reg [7:0] D,
   output reg [7:0] E,
   output reg [7:0] F
     );

   always @(*) begin
     if (A>B && B>C) begin
         D <= A;
         E <= B;
         F <= C;
       end
     else if (A>C && C>B) begin
         D <= A;
         E <= C;
         F <= B;
       end
     else if (B>C && C>A) begin
         D <= B;
         E <= C;
         F <= A;
       end
     else if (B>A && A>C) begin
         D <= B;
         E <= A;
         F <= C;
       end
     else if (C>A && A>B) begin
         D <= C;
         E <= A;
         F <= B;
       end
       else begin
         D <= C;
         E <= B;
         F <= A;
       end
     end
 endmodule
```

And this is the new test bench:

```
module testcomp;
  reg [7:0] A, B, C;
  wire [7:0] D, E, F;

    comparator uut (
      .A(A),
      .B(B),
      .C(C),
      .D(D),
      .E(E),
      .F(F)
    );

    initial begin
      A = 0;
      repeat (3) begin
        B = 0;
        repeat (3) begin
          C = 0;
          repeat (3) begin
            #10;
            $display ("TESTING A=%d, B=%d, and C=%d yields D=%d, E=%d, F=%d", A, B, C, D, E, F);
            if (A>B && B>C && D!=A && E!=B && F!=C) begin
                $display ("ERROR!");
                $finish;
            end
            if (A>C && C>B && D!=A && E!=C && F!=B) begin
                $display ("ERROR!");
                $finish;
            end
            if (B>A && A>C && D!=B && E!=A && F!=C) begin
                $display ("ERROR!");
                $finish;
            end
            if (B>C && C>A && D!=B && E!=C && F!=A) begin
                $display ("ERROR!");
                $finish;
            end
            if (C>A && A>B && D!=C && E!=A && F!=B) begin
                $display ("ERROR!");
                $finish;
            end
            if (C>B && B>A && D!=C && E!=B && F!=A) begin
                $display ("ERROR!");
                $finish;
            end
              C = C + 1;
            end
              B = B + 1;
            end
            A = A + 1;
    end
  $display ("PASSED!");
  $finish;
 end
endmodule
```

New Post:
This has fixed my issue of comparing values by changing to (A>B && B>C) but when I look at the results I still have some issues. Here are the results:

```
[2016-12-11 14:05:13 EST] iverilog '-Wall' design.sv testbench.sv  && unbuffer vvp a.out  
TESTING A=  0, B=  0, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  0, F=  0
TESTING A=  0, B=  0, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  0, F=  0
TESTING A=  0, B=  0, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  0, F=  0
**TESTING A=  0, B=  1, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  1, F=  0**
TESTING A=  0, B=  1, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  1, F=  0
TESTING A=  0, B=  1, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  0
**TESTING A=  0, B=  2, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  2, F=  0**
TESTING A=  0, B=  2, and C=  1 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  0
TESTING A=  0, B=  2, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  2, F=  0
**TESTING A=  1, B=  0, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  0, F=  1**
**TESTING A=  1, B=  0, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  0, F=  1**
TESTING A=  1, B=  0, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  0
**TESTING A=  1, B=  1, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  1, F=  1**
TESTING A=  1, B=  1, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  1, F=  1
TESTING A=  1, B=  1, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  1
TESTING A=  1, B=  2, and C=  0 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  0
**TESTING A=  1, B=  2, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  2, F=  1**
TESTING A=  1, B=  2, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  2, F=  1
**TESTING A=  2, B=  0, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  0, F=  2**
TESTING A=  2, B=  0, and C=  1 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  0
**TESTING A=  2, B=  0, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  0, F=  2**
TESTING A=  2, B=  1, and C=  0 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  0
**TESTING A=  2, B=  1, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  1, F=  2**
**TESTING A=  2, B=  1, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  1, F=  2**
**TESTING A=  2, B=  2, and C=  0 yields D=  0, E=  2, F=  2**
**TESTING A=  2, B=  2, and C=  1 yields D=  1, E=  2, F=  2**
TESTING A=  2, B=  2, and C=  2 yields D=  2, E=  2, F=  2
PASSED!
Done
```

As you can see by those marked/starred, there are still issues with it not comparing the values correctly. Is it something in my code or did I miss a constraint that is not allowing this to function properly?

Original:

The main issue is that I keep getting stuck into the else branch of the design code's main code(when I was using (A>B>C) to compare values in the code). I'm guessing that the numbers aren't comparing at all in the main code and that the issue lies wherein how I tried to compare the values. Can you please help me find a way to compare the three 8-bit inputs properly to avoid being stuck in the else branch? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @toolic I did as you said and received success for part of the values. Unfortunately there are still values that don't compare correctly. Can you please take a second look at the code and see if I have made a mistake in implementing your method? I could not ascertain a pattern myself and looking at it up to 16 in the test bench gave me a head ache so I tried a smaller number.

Comment: @toolic Thank you. Unfortunately though, it didn't fix the issue with the values. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue. I needed to be careful of times when the value could be the same. I have thus ended with the following code:

```
module comparator (
  input clock,
  input wire [7:0] A,
  input wire [7:0] B,
  input wire [7:0] C,
  output reg [7:0] D,
  output reg [7:0] E,
  output reg [7:0] F
    );

  always @(*) begin
    if (A>=B && B>=C) begin
        D <= A;
        E <= B;
        F <= C;
      end
    else if (A>=C && C>=B) begin
        D <= A;
        E <= C;
        F <= B;
      end
    else if (B>=C && C>=A) begin
        D <= B;
        E <= C;
        F <= A;
      end
    else if (B>=A && A>=C) begin
        D <= B;
        E <= A;
        F <= C;
      end
    else if (C>=A && A>=B) begin
        D <= C;
        E <= A;
        F <= B;
      end
      else begin
        D <= C;
        E <= B;
        F <= A;
      end
    end
endmodule
```

And the testbench:

```
module testcomp;
  input clock;
  reg [7:0] A, B, C;
  wire [7:0] D, E, F;

    comparator uut (
      .clock(clock),
      .A(A),
      .B(B),
      .C(C),
      .D(D),
      .E(E),
      .F(F)
    );

    initial begin
      A = 0;
      repeat (255) begin
        B = 0;
        repeat (255) begin
          C = 0;
          repeat (255) begin
            #10;
            $display ("TESTING A=%h, B=%h, and C=%h yields D=%h, E=%h, F=%h", A, B, C, D, E, F);
       if (A>B && B>C && D!=A && E!=B && F!=C) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
        end
        if (A>C && C>B && D!=A && E!=C && F!=B) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
        end
        if (B>A && A>C && D!=B && E!=A && F!=C) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
        end
        if (B>C && C>A && D!=B && E!=C && F!=A) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
        end
        if (C>A && A>B && D!=C && E!=A && F!=B) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
        end
        if (C>B && B>A && D!=C && E!=B && F!=A) begin
            $display ("ERROR!");
            $finish;
        end
          C = C + 1;
        end
          B = B + 1;
        end
        A = A + 1;
    end
  $display ("PASSED!");
  $finish;
 end
endmodule
```

With the following extracted(pulled from middle) results:

```
[2016-12-12 08:56:45 EST] iverilog '-Wall' design.sv testbench.sv  && unbuffer vvp a.out
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=05 yields D=0c, E=05, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=06 yields D=0c, E=06, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=07 yields D=0c, E=07, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=08 yields D=0c, E=08, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=09 yields D=0c, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=0a yields D=0c, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=0b yields D=0c, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=0c yields D=0c, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=0d yields D=0d, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0c, and C=0e yields D=0e, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=09 yields D=0d, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=0a yields D=0d, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=0b yields D=0d, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=0c yields D=0d, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=0d yields D=0d, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=0e yields D=0e, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=0f yields D=0f, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=fd yields D=fd, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0d, and C=fe yields D=fe, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=00 yields D=0e, E=00, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=01 yields D=0e, E=01, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=02 yields D=0e, E=02, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=03 yields D=0e, E=03, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=04 yields D=0e, E=04, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=05 yields D=0e, E=05, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=06 yields D=0e, E=06, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=07 yields D=0e, E=07, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=08 yields D=0e, E=08, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=09 yields D=0e, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=0a yields D=0e, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=0b yields D=0e, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=0c yields D=0e, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=0d yields D=0e, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=0e yields D=0e, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=0f yields D=0f, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=10 yields D=10, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0e, and C=11 yields D=11, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0f, and C=fd yields D=fd, E=0f, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=0f, and C=fe yields D=fe, E=0f, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=00 yields D=10, E=00, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=01 yields D=10, E=01, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=02 yields D=10, E=02, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=03 yields D=10, E=03, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=04 yields D=10, E=04, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=05 yields D=10, E=05, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=06 yields D=10, E=06, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=07 yields D=10, E=07, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=08 yields D=10, E=08, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=09 yields D=10, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=0a yields D=10, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=0b yields D=10, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=0c yields D=10, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=0d yields D=10, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=0e yields D=10, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=0f yields D=10, E=0f, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=10 yields D=10, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=11 yields D=11, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=12 yields D=12, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=13 yields D=13, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=fd yields D=fd, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=10, and C=fe yields D=fe, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=00 yields D=11, E=00, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=01 yields D=11, E=01, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=02 yields D=11, E=02, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=03 yields D=11, E=03, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=04 yields D=11, E=04, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=05 yields D=11, E=05, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=06 yields D=11, E=06, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=07 yields D=11, E=07, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=08 yields D=11, E=08, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=09 yields D=11, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=0a yields D=11, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=0b yields D=11, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=0c yields D=11, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=0d yields D=11, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=0e yields D=11, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=0f yields D=11, E=0f, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=10 yields D=11, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=11 yields D=11, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=12 yields D=12, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=13 yields D=13, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=14 yields D=14, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=15 yields D=15, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=16 yields D=16, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=17 yields D=17, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=fd yields D=fd, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=11, and C=fe yields D=fe, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=00 yields D=12, E=00, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=01 yields D=12, E=01, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=02 yields D=12, E=02, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=03 yields D=12, E=03, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=04 yields D=12, E=04, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=05 yields D=12, E=05, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=06 yields D=12, E=06, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=07 yields D=12, E=07, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=08 yields D=12, E=08, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=09 yields D=12, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=0a yields D=12, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=0b yields D=12, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=0c yields D=12, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=0d yields D=12, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=0e yields D=12, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=0f yields D=12, E=0f, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=10 yields D=12, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=11 yields D=12, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=12 yields D=12, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=13 yields D=13, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=14 yields D=14, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=15 yields D=15, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=16 yields D=16, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=17 yields D=17, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=fd yields D=fd, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=12, and C=fe yields D=fe, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=00 yields D=13, E=00, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=01 yields D=13, E=01, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=02 yields D=13, E=02, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=03 yields D=13, E=03, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=04 yields D=13, E=04, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=05 yields D=13, E=05, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=06 yields D=13, E=06, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=07 yields D=13, E=07, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=08 yields D=13, E=08, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=09 yields D=13, E=09, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=0a yields D=13, E=0a, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=0b yields D=13, E=0b, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=0c yields D=13, E=0c, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=0d yields D=13, E=0d, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=0e yields D=13, E=0e, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=0f yields D=13, E=0f, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=10 yields D=13, E=10, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=11 yields D=13, E=11, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=12 yields D=13, E=12, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=13 yields D=13, E=13, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=14 yields D=14, E=13, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=15 yields D=15, E=13, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=16 yields D=16, E=13, F=00
TESTING A=00, B=13, and C=17 yields D=17, E=13, F=00
Done
```